# S3 POST policy + CloudFront pre-signed URLs

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Does CloudFront accept custom S3 POST policies ([see here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTForms.html#HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy))?

Maybe, only CloudFront-specific policies ([see here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/cloudfront-signed-url.html)) are supported?

Maybe, my best option is [S3 Transfer Acceleration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html)?

Specifically, I'm uploading a file (via POST request) to S3 using a pre-signed url.

I would prefer to use a pre-signed CloudFront url (where my CloudFront distribution has an S3 origin).

Additionally, I want to use a "custom policy" for the pre-signed url, so I can define a `content-length-range` and other conditions.

---

#### Edit 1:

I'm doing this using `XMLHttpRequest`, not a browser-based form.

My prerequisites are:

- It must be a pre-signed HTTPS url
- Enforce `content-length-range` using a custom S3 POST policy
- CloudFront is preferred, but S3 is acceptable

Other information:

- I have 2 CloudFront distributions (one that requires pre-signed urls, and one that does not)
- The pre-signed urls are created on a NodeJS server and sent to the client

Comment: Let's clarify... S3 policy documents are used for browser-based form `POST` *uploads*.  Is that what you're referring to?  What -- exactly -- are you wanting to accomplish?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Updated the question. Let me know if more information is required. :)

Comment: Yes, this should work as expected through CloudFront using an S3 policy... but S3 `POST` doesn't use a pre-signed URL.  The signature is embedded in the form that you `POST`.  Note that the request is always `POST / HTTP/1.1` because the object key is also part of the form, not the URL. Try it?  Also, does your CloudFront distribution also require pre-signed URLs?  That could get a little messy, but it can be resolved also.  Please advise.

Comment: Transfer acceleration is certainly easier, but 2x the cost... $0.04/GB uploaded vs $0.02/GB uploaded.  Otherwise, there is literally no difference in performance... S3 Transfer Acceleration is "secretly" (not really a secret) is actually built on the CloudFront infrastructure, but the CloudFront components are automatically-provisioned when you enable the feature on a bucket (and caching is disabled, for downloads).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Okay, question updated. Can I simply use a `cloudfront.net` url with its `Policy="base64-encoded s3 post policy"` (and the necessary `Signature` and `Key-Pair-Id` params)?

Comment: I assume that `Policy` would be mistaken for a CloudFront policy (which is different).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133363/discussion-between-aleclarson-and-michael-sqlbot).